# Ember.Instrumentation API example

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been going through [this](http://bradleypriest.com/2012/10/15/whats-new-in-emberjs-16/) post regarding newly added features in EmberJS. One of them being [Ember.Instrumentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/134fc61b764ef5b464ab3ebef968716b7df5c50c), can anyone explain where do we use it, if possible with an example...Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Why

Instrumentation in general is a way to measure performance and other metrics in your app by subscribing to namespaced listeners. It can also be useful for debugging.

### Example

I can't take credit for making this fiddle, I only saw it last night at the NYC ember.js meetup, but this should provide some context:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Pn3f/6/

In my attempt to figure out who presented this, I could only find his meetup profile: http://www.meetup.com/EmberJS-NYC/members/6706336/

To see the magic happen, open your console and start marking students as 'here.'

See the StudentView near the top and Em.Subscribe at the bottom.

```js
// In a view
Em.instrument("student.here", this.get('content'), function() {
    //mark student as in attendance
    this.set('inAttendance', !this.get('inAttendance'));
  }, this);
},
```

...

```
Em.subscribe('*', {
  ts: null,
  before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
    ts = timestamp;
    //console.log('    before: ', name, JSON.stringify(payload));
    //return 'HelloFromThePast';
  },
  after: function(name, timestamp, payload, beforeRet) {
    //log metrics
    //record analytics
    //profile app
    console.log('instrument: ', name, JSON.stringify(payload), beforeRet, timestamp - ts);
  }
});
```

### Side note

What's even cooler is that you can subscribe to ember's use of instrumentation by using the wildcard.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmazza/sUvdg/

### Documentation

See the documentation for details: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html

Comment: thanks fr the info...seems that doc has been recently updated wrt to instrumentation